# Event consumption in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, windows-phone-7, delegates

I have a very simple app written in Silverlight for Windows Phone, where I try to use events. In my App.xaml.cs code behind I have implemented a GeoCoordinateWatcher which registers a gCWatche_PositionChanged method. This works ok, method is called after the position has been changed. **What I want to do is fire an other event** lets say DBUpdatedEvent after DB has been updated in the gCWatche_PositionChanged method.

For this i delclared in the App.xaml.cs

```
public delegate void DBUpdateEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

and I have in my App class:

```
   public event DBUpdateEventHandler DBUpdated;
```

the event is fired like this in the end of gCWatche_PositionChanged method like this:

```
       OnDBUpdateEvent(new EventArgs());
```

and also I have declared :

```
    protected virtual void OnDBUpdateEvent(EventArgs e)
    {

        if (DBUpdated != null)
        {

            DBUpdated(this, e);
        }

    }
```

Now I need to **consume this event** in my **other Windows Phone app** page which is a separate class PhoneApplicationPage.

So I declared this method in this other Phone Page:

```
    public void DBHasBeenUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DB UPDATE EVENT CATCHED");
    }
```

And in the constructor of this page I declared:

```
        DBUpdateEventHandler dbEH = new DBUpdateEventHandler(DBHasBeenUpdated);
```

But when I test the application event is fired (OnDBUpdateEvent is called, but DBUpdated is null, therefore DBUpdated is not called - strange) and I have a problem that the other Phone Page is not catching the event at all...

Any suggestions? How to catch that event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create event as static event.

```
public static event DBUpdateEventHandler DBUpdated;
```

And the handler should be attached with event as below in your page constructor:

```
App.DBUpdated+=new DBUpdateEventHandler(DBHasBeenUpdated);
```

Answer (score 0):

When we want to register to an event, we do it like:

```
class A
{
    public event DBUpdateEventHandler DBUpdated;
}

class B
{
    private A _a;
    //let requirement want to register when the object is initialized
    constructor()
    {
        _a = new A();
        _a.DBUpdated += OnDBUpdateEvent;
    }
}
```

In your case you can make your event static member.
and register to it in your `PhoneApplicationPage` as:

```
App.DBUpdated -= DBHasBeenUpdated;
App.DBUpdated += DBHasBeenUpdated;
```